# Finding an app for MS Sharing image sample?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, datacontracts

I've been tinkering with this to implement the share charm into my app: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84

It's been a great resource, but I seem to be having trouble getting Image sharing to work when using SetBitmap().

When using the Delayed Renderer example or commenting out the StorageItem part of the image sample, the share panel comes up, but it says I don't have any apps available to share that data with. I've tried a couple of different photo apps from the strore. Is using StorageItems in the data contract the way most if not all apps accept image data, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best app to use to test your Sharing Source app is the [Sharing Target sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782).  Download that app and run it ... from then on, it will show up as a share target for all types. It will also show you everything that you are populating as part of the Data Requested callback.

It's hard to say what most apps are doing at this point ... I would think any app that is expecting an image would support [StandardDataFormat.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats.aspx), but you never know.

Comment: Came here to say this. That sample is so incredibly valuable for testing your own Share Source apps...